# retrieving google chrome booksmarks after uninstall

Tags: google-chrome

I had recently (and unfortunately) uninstalled the google chrome browser from my computer -while completely forgetting about the dozens of bookmarks I had stored on it.

Is there a method/directory to retrieve these chrome bookmarks after having already uninstalled???

Please do help! would be a lifesaver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you syncronised your bookmarks (a newish feature of Chrome), they would be available in your 'Google Docs', they are often hidden and you might have to show them via changing filters.

Comment: Ha! Glad you were able to get them back :D

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how thorough the uninstaller is, the bookmarks may still be available under your Application data directory

http://ellisweb.net/2008/09/where-does-google-chrome-store-user-history-profile-and-bookmarks/

Otherwise you're probably out of luck.